# How can I replace this Numpy function so it is an explicit loop?

Tags: python

This is what I have and I no Longer need the Numpy Function,
vib(ite) is used as a set of values in a table.
Any help is appreciated.

```
def vibr(nu):
    return (nu + .5)*w_e - ((nu + .5)**2)*xw_e

num_of_iter = 20
E_vib = np.zeros((num_of_iter, 1))
for ite in range(num_of_iter):
   E_vib[ite] = vibr(ite)
```

Obviously indentation is correct but cannot show it properly on here??

Comment: we can only speculate without the definition of `vibr`, but creating an array of the values with something like `np.arange(20)` and passing it entirely to `vibr()` may work

Comment: def vibr(nu,)
    return (nu + .5)*w_e - ((nu + .5)**2)*xw_e

Comment: that is its definition how would this be written what you are explaining?

Comment: You should tell us more about your table, or not ? For tablecelement in the table ..... table element = vibr(table element) ??

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for a range of values with a simple function that performs some math on the input, this may be enough

```py
arr = np.arange(20)
result = vibr(arr)
```

This works because because math operations on numpy arrays are [broadcast to all members](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/whatisnumpy.html)

For example

```
>>> def test_fn(a):
...     return a**2 + 3
...
>>> test_fn(np.arange(10))
array([ 3,  4,  7, 12, 19, 28, 39, 52, 67, 84])
```